# Can I Hide the Spreadsheet Tabs In An Excel HTML Document?

Tags: html, excel, tabs

It is posssible to Hide the Worksheet Tabs in the Excel Window by deselecting

```
Tools > Options > View > Sheet Tabs
```

However if you save the Spreadsheet as an HTML Document and the open this with Internet Explorer, the Worksheet Tabs reappear...

Does anyone know of a way to prevent them from appearing in IE as well?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How would the user navigate between sheets?

Comment: With hyperlinks - there is the Option to navigate to a "Place in this Document" which works fine

Comment: I figured that was the case, but I have never tried to use Excel file inside Internet Explorer as an HTML document... good luck! +1 for interesting question :)

Comment: I publish my Website entirely from Excel; not that pretty but very easy

Comment: not sure if you've seen this: http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=52956  Suggests hiding them before you view as web page/HTML preview? Not sure if it will help you, but it's worth a shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

open the html file with notepad or other similar. find this script

```
 <frame src="YOUREXCELFILENAME_files/tabstrip.html" name="frTabs" marginwidth=0 marginheight=0>
```

and just delete it than save.